# How to push data as an array of an index to firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an keys and want to push it to a specific item in my DB and i use .push() method when I add an item to firebase but it does not work as what I need it generates a new key and inside it add index

what i got

```
--Orders
  -LASDAWWDMASDsad
  -0:"orderOne"
  -DAWKDAWKWKDKADW
  -0:"OrderTwo"
  ...
```

What I need

```
--Orders
  -0:"orderOne"
  -1:"orderTwo"
  -2:"orderThree"
  ...
```

Code

```
const displayTable = document.getElementById('display-table')
  ,   lipProCkBxs  = document.querySelectorAll('#lip-pro input[type=checkbox]')
  ,   tableTotal   = document.querySelector('#display-table tfoot tr td:last-child')

const {snapshotVal, uid, serviceDB} = this.state;

onPress: () => {
            let arr = [snapshotVal];
            // console.log(arr); // ["orderOne"]
            database()
              .ref(`Providers/users/${uid}`)
              .child('rejectedOrders')
              .push(arr)
              .then(
                () => console.log('Done'),
                setTimeout(() => {
                  this.props.navigation.goBack();
                }, 200),
              )
              .catch(error => console.log('@error', error));
            }
```

SOLVED By JS :"D

i make a query to get the length of a rejectedOrders then when i want to updates i just increase the length +1
And it works well :3

```
componentDidMount() {
  let uid = auth().currentUser.uid;

  database()
    .ref(`Providers/users/${uid}`)
    .child('rejectedOrders')
    .on('value', snapshot =>
    this.setState({arrlength: snapshot.val().length - 1}),
    );
}

onPress: () => {
  let arr = [snapshotKey];
  console.log(arr);

  let updates = {};
  // updates[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)] = snapshotKey;
  updates[arrlength + 1] = snapshotKey;
  database()
    .ref(`Providers/users/${uid}`)
    .child('rejectedOrders')
    // .push(...arr)
    .update(updates)
    .then(...)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set()` instead of `push()`:

```
database()
              .ref(`Providers/users/${uid}`)
              .child('rejectedOrders')
              .set(arr)
              .then(
                () => console.log('Done'),
                setTimeout(() => {
                  this.props.navigation.goBack();
                }, 200),
              )
              .catch(error => console.log('@error', error));
}
```

Comment: but when I add any new item it will replace the previous with the new one and i don't need this case

Comment: Then use update() https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data

Comment: it will do the same :( I think no way to save items like this? I searched before ask but I can't find any answer to achieve what I want

Comment: Check my question for seeing what I made haha :"D

Answer (score 0):

Before save get the list of data and pass it ['data1','data2'.....]. It will save like 0: data1, 1: data2 .....

firebaseDBref.set([data1, data2]);